# Adding elements(append) to json array using multithreading

Tags: java, json, multithreading

I have a json array.For each element of this array i want to make additional query and add the query result to those specific array element. these additional query i want to be multithreading. please suggest an efficient way.

Comment: Can't you just parse it to some object and operate with it just like with simple object in multithreaded environment?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?